# Creating mac software activation

Tags: macos, activation, license-key

I am just about done writing a killer application for the mac, however I would like to charge money for this one, as there isn't a lot of applications out there like this one.  So I was thinking of using some sort of activation or license key.  I've looked around but details on how to do it is relatively scarce. How can I do this in a way that will be both easy to implement in my software, as well as something that doesn't require me to run software on my server, or depend on other companies running it on their servers, but if I have to I will. I don't want anything that will require me to pay money to some company to do it for me, paypal will get a big enough cut, I don't want another company taking a cut.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [Aquatic Prime](http://www.aquaticmac.com/).

Answer (score 2):

There's also CocoaFob:

http://www.turbodad.com/articles/48/cocoafob-released

which works with Potion Store:

http://www.potionfactory.com/potionstore